# Favicon size in Google Chrome bookmarks

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, favicon, bookmarks

Does anybody know how to show a larger favicon in the **Google Chrome** bookmarks on my mobiles devices, like this **fd-favicon**? (image)

My website supports the favicon sizes:

```
16x16
72x72
114x114
120x120
144x144
152x152
```

Image:
http://oi60.tinypic.com/1yl6ag.jpg

Thanks.

Comment: I meet the same problem.Unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

[Google recommends to use the Apple touch icon and a 196x196 PNG icon](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/installtohomescreen). If you use both, [Chrome will almost always use the Apple touch icon](http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility).

In other words, your HTML code should contain something like:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
```

See Apple specs for more information on the [Apple touch icon](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html).

You can generate all pictures and HTML code with this [favicon generator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/). Full disclosure: I'm the author of this site.